# Find $M+m$, if $m\le(\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+\frac{2}{3})\cos^{2017}{(\frac{\pi}{3}x+\frac{2\pi}{3})}+2x+3\le M$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

> Let $$f(x)=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)\cos^{2017}{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}x+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)}+2x+3,~~-2015\le x\le 2017$$
>
> Assmue that the maximum if $M$,and the minimum of the value is $m$.Find the $M+m=(  ~~)$

$A:5~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $B: 10~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$C:~1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$D:0~~~~~~$

Maybe this problem have some nice relation?because we can't to find the maxium of the value and also the minimum value

Comment: the 2017th power of any (co)sine function is going to be extremely close to a constant.

Comment: @Jacob Claassen but they are either $-1,0,1$ which value to choose for and how to justify that they are maxima,minima

Comment: @archis they could be any number between -1, 1